# Mod_rewrite: How to catch .php files?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

### **I'm trying to catch all .php requests so that my visitors won't be able to see the php magic**

I want `example.com/home` to be redirected to `example.com/index.php`, but I don't want direct access to `example.com/index.php`

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
> ```

Although it seems to work at first glance, **it doesn't prevent users from visiting example.com/index.php directly.**

**How would I solve this?**

---

In reply to an answer:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^home/?$ /index.php?category=1 [L]
```

**`example.com/home` outputs `example.com/category=1`**

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/87693/how-to-prevent-infinite-redirect-loop-on-htaccess

Comment: I updated the question. It's not so much about the infinite loop as it is about the 'catch all .php'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

What that will do is, if the user tries to go directly to index.php, it will *redirect* them to the root of the site. Otherwise, it will run your existing rules, passing anything through to index.PHP.

Comment: The problem is that redirecting test/(.*)/?$ to index.php?q=$1 results in example.com/?q=variable

Comment: It shouldn't, if the index.php rewrite rule is first... I'll test this for you tomorrow and confirm.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to the test result. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could run a `preg_match()` for .php on the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable, then use a `header()` to redirect accordingly. For example, in index.php:

```
if(preg_match('/\.php/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    header('Location: home');
    die();
}
```

That has no support for any query string parameters, however, as I don't know what your format is in your /home rewrite. `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` will be your friend here, though.